# No references w/ linux + apa6e

Tags: cross-referencing

I recently switched from a windows box to linux mint + cinnamon.  The files I normally run on windows will not print the references.  I'm using texstudio with tex live.  Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[leavefloats]{apa6e}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber,bibencoding=latin1]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{testb.bib}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\defbibheading{bibliography}{%
\section{\normalfont\refname}}

\title{title}
\shorttitle{ti}
\author{me}
\authornote{note}
\abstract{abs}
\date{\today} 
\begin{document}
\maketitle

MWE

\parencite{Mcvee2005}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

The bib file is:

```
@ARTICLE{Mcvee2005,
  author = {Mcvee, Mary B. and Dunsmore, Kailonnie and Gavelek, James R.},
  title = {{Schema theory revisited}},
  journal = {Review of Educational Research},
  year = {2005},
  volume = {75},
  pages = {531-566}
}
```

Here's a link to the log file:  http://dl.dropbox.com/u/61803503/test.log

How can I get the references to print using the new linux environment with tex live.

Note:
Running the following from the command line:

```
pdftex test.tex
bibtex test.aux
```

results in:

```
.
tyler@trinker ~/Desktop/MWE $ bibtex  test.aux
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2012/Debian)
The top-level auxiliary file: test.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file test.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file test.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file test.aux
```

Comment: You have `backend=biber`, so you need to run `biber` and not `bibtex`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Configure TeXStudio to run `biber` instead of `bibtex` if you want to have `biber` as your backend.

Click

> Options > Configure TeXStudio > Build > Default Bibliography > Biber

Otherwise, replace `backend=biber` option to `backend=bibtex`. As mentioned in comment, when using command line/terminal, you have to run `biber test` when using the `biber` backend. (Note that the omission of the file extension.)

Comment: Just wanted to add this for future searchers.  This is what I had to do exactly: `Options > Configure TeXStudio > Build > Commands > biber %.bcf` using texstudio 2.3.  Thanks a ton hpesoj626.

Comment: With TeXstudio 2.5.1 (SVN 3484), you don't have to specify `%.bcf`. Also, pressing F6 will automatically run every command you need to compile your document (i.e., it will automatically detect whether you need to do `makeindex` and run that for you).

Comment: Thanks good tip.  I downloaded the newest version (2.5.1) and your directions are spot on.